# How to copy or get access to the file (.zip) from received Email on BlackBerry z10?

Tags: file, email, copy, blackberry-10

Need help in copying a file from received email on BlackBerry z10. Allredy tryed to find a solution without sucesss.

Task is to load a file from received email by clicking on it. Allredy implement, that my App opens on clicking a file with ending .kdp.

bar-descriptor.xml:

```
    <invoke-target id="com.example.MyApp">
<invoke-target-type>application</invoke-target-type>
<invoke-target-name>Name of my App</invoke-target-name>
<icon>
    <image>icon.png</image>
</icon>
<filter>
    <action>bb.action.OPEN</action>
    <mime-type>*</mime-type>
    <property var="exts" value="kdp"/>
    <property var="uris" value="file://,data://"/>
</filter>
</invoke-target>
```

next step i connect InvokeManager with a slot:

```
    m_invokeManager = new InvokeManager(this);
    bool connectResult;
    connectResult = m_invokeManager->connect(m_invokeManager, SIGNAL(invoked(const bb::system::InvokeRequest&)), this, SLOT(onInvoke(const bb::system::InvokeRequest&)));
```

What i'm looking for is a good solution for copying the file, which was clicked:

```
    void ApplicationUI::onInvoke(const bb::system::InvokeRequest& request) {



qDebug() << "called on clicked file.kdp";
InvokeRequest myRequest = (request);
myRequest.setFileTransferMode(bb::system::FileTransferMode::CopyReadOnly);
QFile appFile(QDir::currentPath() + "/data/data.kdp");
appFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
appFile.close();
QString from = myRequest.uri().toString();
QString to = QDir::currentPath() + "/data/data.kdp";
bool test = QFile::copy(from, to);// don't work

qDebug() << test; // <--is false, don't work
qDebug() << "URL r: " + request.uri().toString();//<-- can see the path to file, but allways different
qDebug() << "URL m: " + myRequest.uri().toString();}
```

data.kdp is a like a zip format, need just to copy the file from email to my App...
please help:D

Comment: QString m_uri = request.uri().toString();


QFile textfile(m_uri.replace("file://","").toUtf8().constData());

Comment: Add as answer if it is what you wanted, so others can see the solution as well

Answer (score 0):

QString m_uri = request.uri().toString(); QFile textfile(m_uri.replace("file://","").toUtf8().constData());
Just replace "file://" in path!